# How to Translate ASP Request Page Statement in a form for PHP use

Tags: php, asp-classic

I don't know ASP and I am trying to convert a form over to be used in a PHP page.  I have this between the form tags <%If Request("RequestPage").Count >= 1 Then FRPMulti%>.  Can someone tell me what the ASP part means?

```
<input type="hidden" name="StartingSUTypePage" value="<%response.write(varRequestPage)%>" />
<%If Request("RequestPage").Count >= 1 Then FRPMulti%>
<input type="hidden" name="RequestPage" value="<%response.write(varRequestPage)%>" />
```

Comment: It possible it got down voted because 1) It doesn't show you have done any research, as a quick search on some keywords would bring up useful pages telling you what those ASP commands do. 2) The title was very unspecific and broad (I've updated it) 3) You didn't specify what particular aspect was what you were asking about.     

All of these can cause people to down vote a question.

Comment: I had tried doing some research, mostly on .Count >= 1 Then FRPMulti which revealed nothing.  I tried Request("RequestPage").Count >= 1 Then FRPMulti which also showed no results.  So to get more context for my question I included more data to help get my question answered even-though I knew what most of it meant.  The result was I did get the answer I was looking for and it helped me solve my problem. Maybe people shouldn't be so quick to judge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`response.write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525585(v=vs.90)) basically maps to `echo`, and you might see it in both long and short form which this code shows:

**asp**

```
<% response.write(varRequestPage) %>
<%= varRequestPage %>
```

**php**

```php
<?php echo $varRequestPage ?>
<?= $varRequestPage ?>
```

[`Request()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524948(v=vs.90)) maps to the [`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) super global. The major difference between these two is that ASP searches GET, POST, cookies and server variables, in that order (ignoring client certificates), and the first one found wins. PHP on the other hand searches GET, POST and cookies (with the latter not default anymore as of PHP 7), and each time it finds one it overrides the previous call.

```
<%If Request("RequestPage").Count >= 1 Then FRPMulti%>
```

```php
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST('RequestPage')){ /* Do something */ } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That helped me solve my problem!